# How to stylize/design maps without tools like m*p b*x (paid tools) using OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, design

I would like to know, how I'm able to stylize/design maps without using paid tools. I would love to work with *Openstreetmap* data. I know I could stylize these data in free GIS software like QGIS but after uploading to server I would like to add some additional functionalities using JavaScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to customize?

Comment: Probably, i will add OSM data via postGIS to QGIS. Here i would like to design data roads, polygons, labels, specific properties for each zoom level (like i can do it in Mapbox studio for example) after uploading to server i would like to add some additional functionalities using Javascript but i'm not sure if it's possible to use _CartoDB.js_ for example in my own server.

Comment: Do you want to deliver pre-rendered tiles (which is pretty fast, but static), or vector data (which can be queried, but client-side rendering is slower)?

Comment: I think better solution would be deliver vector data. Although pre-rendered tiles like you said is statistic, in this case i would like to add additional functionality via javascripts to make map "interactive", you know i don't want to have only "dead" map. So after all i'm not sure what is better to use vector or pre-rendered tiles.

Comment: You can display vector data on top of background tiles as well.

Comment: Do you think that i'm able to use javascript from other services ony my own server? Isn't it misuse? Maybe it's absolutely impossible. I'm not sure

Comment: There might be opensource javascripts for the same purpose. I don't know if you need (and can install) a server side database to feed the vector data as well.

Comment: @AndreJ Thank you, i will try to find some opensource javascripts maybe i will be successful.